# org-mode headings renders markdown link syntax of inner code block, how to prevent it from happening?

Tags: org-mode, doom, markdown, markdown-mode

I am using Doom Emacs with bundled org-mode and markdown-mode.

I have org-mode text snippet like this:

```
*** test
**** http://example.com
**** block
#+begin_src

http://example.com/

#+end_src
**** markdown block
#+begin_src markdown

http://example.com/

#+end_src
**** markdown link block
#+begin_src markdown

[example.com](http://example.com/)

#+end_src
**** markdown link block
#+begin_src markdown

[example.com](http://example.com/)

#+end_src
```

When I collapse headings, it looks like this:

[image]

The first `markdown link block` looks ugly, because the raw Markdown link syntax is rendered partially.

It becomes worse if there are multiple links in the Markdown block. Code blocks (enclosed by ``` and ```) look more ugly.

My question is, why it happened and how can I fix it. (I want to hide ugly stuff from the headings)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It's probably something to do with your init file. Start with `emacs -q` and see if you can reproduce it there. If not, bisect your init file to figure out who messes things up.

Comment: @NickD thank you for your comment. You are right, `emacs -q` didn't have any problems even on my local machine. It brought me up an idea to start over from scratch by uninstalling/reinstalling Doom Emacs. The problem has gone now.